# silverlight create rectangle with button click

Tags: c#, silverlight

I want to create silverlight application in C#, I added a button and I want to create rectangles with each click one by one, now i managed to create one rectangle but the problem is that i don't know how to change the location of the next rectangle to be created?

Please Help I want each click create rectangle next to another?!
Thanks
here is the code:

C#

```
enter code here

public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Canvas c = new Canvas();

            Button b = new Button();
            Canvas.SetLeft(b, -50);
            Canvas.SetTop(b, 20);
            b.Width = 75;
            b.Height = 23;
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(b);
            b.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(b_Click);
        }

        void b_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
            rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan);
            Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, 100);
            Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, 100);
            rectangle.Width = 200;
            rectangle.Height = 100;

            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(rectangle);

        }


Xaml:
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="215" Width="292">

    </Canvas>
```

Comment: How should the rectangle placements be related to each other?  The next rectangle placed directly to the left of the previous?  Directly below?  To the left until a the right hand border then begin a new line?  Randomly based some other criteria?  What?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be to create a `StackPanel` or `WrapPanel` and add that to your `Canvas` first. Then add the rectangles to *that*.

This will automatically display the rectangles in a row (if you make the `Orientation` `Horizontal`) or column (`Vertical` - the default).

With more constructs (`Grids` etc.) you can gain more control over where your rectangles are placed.

Answer (score 0):

If you've to change the values which you pass to `SetLeft` and `SetTop` methods of `Canvas`.

So for example, you can do something like this:

```
double left = 100;
double top = 100;
void b_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
    rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan);
    Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, left);  //left is no more a constant
    Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, top);    //top is no more a constant
    rectangle.Width = 200;
    rectangle.Height = 100;
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(rectangle);

    //update left and top 
    left += rectangle.Width + 10; //put some margin!
    if ((left + rectangle.Width) < LayoutRoot.Width)
    { 
       left = 100;
       top += rectangle.Height + 10;
    }
}
```

It updates only `left` value of Rectangle, so that the next rectangle will be placed on the same horizontal line. It does so till there is no space on the left side. Only then it undates `top`  and makes `left = 100` so that the next rectangle below the first row of rectangles. Its like this where `r1`, `r2`, `r3` and so on, are rectangles.

```
| [ r1 ] [ r2 ] [ r3 ] [ r4 ] [ r5 ] | //change only left
| [ r6 ] [ r7 ] [ r8 ] [ r9 ] [ r10] | //change top and make left = 100
//..
```